# normalize signal energy to 0db

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

the question is simple enough but i can't understand what am i missing. So i have a recording, first i frame it with 128samples 50% overlapping, then for each frame i want to calculate the energy of the frame. So i calculate it but when i want to normalize it to 0db i get strange results. Here is my matlab code:

```
for i=1:size(dataF,2)
E(:,i)=20*log10((abs(dataF(:,i)).^2));
emax(:,i)=max(E(:,i));
E1(:,i)=E(:,i)/emax(i);
end
```

Here is the output energy for the first frame and below is the normalized energy to 0db but it is not correct
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQzHa.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KIjw.png)

Any suggestions really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To normalize each frame to 0 dB you have to divide by the maximum *before* the logarithm. Also, you probably need to replace the factor `20` by `10`, since you already squared the data:

```
for i = 1:size(dataF,2)
    dataFmax(:,i) = max(abs(dataF(:,i)).^2)
    E1(:,i) = 10*log10((abs(dataF(:,i)).^2)/dataFmax(:,i));
end
```

Alternatively, you can *subtract* the maximum after the logarithm:

```
for i=1:size(dataF,2)
    E(:,i) = 10*log10((abs(dataF(:,i)).^2));
    emax(:,i) = max(E(:,i));
    E1(:,i) = E(:,i) - emax(i);
end
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Welcome to the site!